# the manytomany does not retrieve the mapped data

Tags: java, spring-boot, many-to-many

Spring boot 2.5.6   (I can't mount a version)

Profil.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Table(name = "t_profil")
public class Profil {
...
...
    @ManyToMany(cascade =  {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "t_profils_fonctionnalites",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "profil_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fonctionnalite_id") }
    )
    public Set<Fonctionnalite> fonctionnalites  = new HashSet(); 
}
```

Fonctionnalite.java

```java
@jakarta.persistence.Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Table(name = "t_fonctionnalite")
public class Fonctionnalite {
...
...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "fonctionnalites", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Profil> profils   = new HashSet();
```

I launch the project, the intermediate table is created: "t_profils_fonctionnalites"
I insert data into this table :

```
profil fonctionnalite
1         1
1         2
2         1
```

controller

```java
...
...
return new ResponseEntity<>(profilDao.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
```

I get this data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "CODEP1",
        "label": "defaut",
        "description": "defaut description1",
        "fonctionnalites": []      
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "CODEP2",
        "label": "label2",
        "description": "description2",
        "fonctionnalites": []        
    },
```

"fonctionnalites":  is empty !   why ?

Comment: the join columns in you `@JoinTable` dont match the columns in your question

Comment: @XtremeBaumer
, I don't understand what you told me?

in t_profils_fonctionnalites, I have as a column: profil_id and fonctionnalite_id

Comment: Your question shows without _id

Comment: I believe the issue is with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` and the conversion of `ResponseEntity` to JSON. Like when the response is converted to JSON, the lazy loaded dependencies are not fetched and can't be loaded at that point

Comment: Try with List Insted of Set for some reason i could not put it to work with set but it worked with list also you need to save all the entitys first then call by them and update with the fonctionnalites put eager on both  and create the Dtos of both Profil and Fonctionnalite while creating the FonctionnalitesDto omit the Profil list

Answer (score 0):

your code is not complete, but I think it happened because your fetch type is lazy,
you have 2 ways

1-  call your functionalities getter to get a list of your functionality

```java
 ...
 ...
 List<Profil> profilList= profilDao.findAll()
 profilList.forEach(profil => {profil.getFonctionnalites()});

 return new ResponseEntity<>(profilList, HttpStatus.OK);
```

2-  change your fetch type to eager

```java
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "fonctionnalites", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private Set<Profil> profils   = new HashSet();
```

Comment: 1.  
```java
List<Profil> profilList= profilDao.findAll();
profilList.forEach(profil -> profil.getFonctionnalites());
return new ResponseEntity<>(profilList, HttpStatus.OK);```
```
It does not recover all the features, it is a bit random. I didn't make a mistake in my table t_profil_fonctionnalite

2.
does not work.